# "Topi pehnana" association with deception

Tags: culture, india

How and when did the phrase *"topi pehnana"* become associated with deceiving someone? My mother tongue is Kannada which also has a similar phrase.

Comment: There is a famous story in which a cap seller wears a cap and removes it so that monkeys do the same

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Also, visit - [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), &. [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @Vivikta Care to direct me to the appropriate stackexchange community for this question? This question doesn't seem to fit in the "off-topic" section https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In my knowledge, there are no such current active Stacks suited for your question. You may try other forums like Quora or Reddit.